# How can I open a .alx or .cod or .prc or .sis file on a computer?

Tags: windows-7, zip, file-types

I found a .zip file of something, and I downloaded it. Inside it were only a .alx and a .cod file (presumably of the same thing). I don't have a Blackberry. Is there a way to open one of the two of them on a computer (Windows 7)? I also found .prc and .sis versions of the same thing.

This file contains text, so I am looking for a way to get the text inside it. I don't know what (if any) interface is before the text.
 I am looking for something like [Ibis Reader](http://ibisreader.com/).

Comment: for sis, use this: http://symbiandev.cdtools.net/

Comment: @tumchaaditya "SIS package is not supported."

Comment: A little more info on 'something' would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

These file types are associated with apps for various mobile devices (e.g. Blackberry Java apps). Since these are generally undocumented proprietary compiled formats, they will probably be of little use to you unless you want to reverse-engineer the app. If you do, patience, trial and error, and a [hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) will be needed.

In general, for unknown package formats it's useful to try opening in 7-zip. It's possible that the archive contains files in some e-book format you can read.

## `alx`

From [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/An-alx-file/ta-p/445186), we see that an `alx` file is an XML document containing a description of the app, e.g.

```
<loader version="1.0">
     <application id="com.rim.samples.device.httpdemo">
          <name>Sample Network Application</name>
          <description>
               Retrieves a sample page over HTTP connection.
          </description>
          <version>1.0</version>
          <vendor>Research In Motion</vendor>
<!-- more metadata truncated -->
     </application>
</loader>
```

You can therefore open it in any text editor, e.g. MS Notepad or Notepad++.

## `cod`

A `cod` file is apparently a proprietary encoding of a compiled Java class file. [This guy has reverse-engineered the format's header](https://drbolsen.wordpress.com/2006/07/26/blackberry-cod-file-format/). With some effort you could probably extract the Java bytecode, and then disassemble it using `javap`. But unless you're interested in reverse-engineering the app, this file probably won't be of any use to you.

## `prc`

I believe this is a [Palm Pilot code format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRC_%28Palm_OS%29). See whether you can find Palm-related computer software that can read it. If it's just an app, it will probably be of little use to you for the same reason as for `cod`.

However, it's also been extended into an e-book format, so you could try opening it in an e-book reader like Calibre if you suspect that's what it contains.

## `sis`

As Journeyman Geek pointed out, [SIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIS_%28file_format%29) is an installer package for Nokia/Symbian devices. It might be a renamed ZIP file (try opening it in 7-zip). Since Symbian is partly open-source, you might be able to find better docs for this format.

Comment: .sis is a nokia/symbian installer package

Comment: `However, it's also been extended into an e-book format, so you could try opening it in an e-book reader like Calibre if you suspect that's what it contains.` I tried with Calibre; it didn't work. `Since Symbian is partly open-source, you might be able to find better docs for this format.` Could you give an example of a type of doc?

Comment: By "docs" I meant documentation for the format.

Comment: I open and read file PRC which is e-book with http://fbreader.org

Answer (score 1):

Use a text editor like Notepad++.  If that doesn't show anything that makes sense, try using a hexeditor [plugin](http://www.mydigitallife.info/use-notepad-as-hex-editor-with-plugin-download-free-winhex-alternative/) with it and see if that works.  You can cut your text out of the files.

> To install the HEX Editor plugin, just extract the HexEditor.dll file
>   from the downloaded ZIP file, and copy it to Notepad++\plugins folder,
>   i.e. C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins or C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Notepad++\plugins.

Comment: The Hexeditor plugin is a .dll file, and I don't know how to open it.

Comment: You use it with Notepad++ (it's a plugin for Notepad++).  The website that I linked to explains how to use it, and I edited my original answer to explain how to install it.

Comment: I did what it said, but it didn't seem to work (see pictures I edited into the question)

Comment: In the top picture, the column on the right has the information in it you are looking for.

Comment: What do I do with it? I was expecting text

Comment: This provides you access to everything in the file.  You'll notice the column on the right has information that is in a human readable format.  There will be other characters (computer readable) among the text that were placed there by whatever originally created the file.  If all you are after is the text, copy out what you want.  The computer isn't going to guess what you want and don't want sine it doesn't have any idea what is a control character, and what isn't.  Since you aren't using what originally created the file, you are going to have to pull out your information by hand.

Comment: I have shown you not only how to open the file, but how to recover the text in the file.  That was what you asked for.

Comment: I changed the picture in the question to show you how it looks. As you can see, it is not readable (except lines 3-5)

Comment: And those are the only human readable characters in the entire file?

Comment: Maybe try reading the other file?

Comment: The other file (.alx) never seemed to work as the .cod one (it always appeared to be a title rather than the text; the whole thing was so short that you couldn't scroll down). Maybe it makes a difference that the file is in a foreign language

Comment: That is one thing I wouldn't know.  I've never had to work with foreign languages.  I apologize, but this may be as far as I can take you using this tool.

Comment: What are those files and what exactly is in those files?
do they all have same content?

for prc file, try using mobipocket reader or one of the programs mentioned here: http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/prc

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a Linux system, you should use the builtin utility named 'file' that guesses the file types based on many different informations, which can give you precious clues on what to do with them. Or sometimes not: if it tells you it's a Berkeley DB that won't tell you what can usefully open it.

To use it, in a terminal, type:

```
# file filename1.alx filename2.cod
```

If you have no easy access to a Linux system, try downloading it for windows on http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm (usage will be the same)

Finally, there are online services that can help you, like http://filext.com/file-extension/COD